# Magento Report Customers Wishlists

Tags: mysql, sql, magento

i am trying to do a report on what is inside customers wishlist, i have come through this query and need more help:

```
   SELECT b.email, c.value AS name, a.updated_at, d.added_at, d.product_id, e.name, SUM(g.qty_ordered) AS purchased
FROM `wishlist` AS a
INNER JOIN customer_entity AS b ON a.customer_id = b.entity_id
INNER JOIN customer_entity_varchar AS c ON a.customer_id = c.entity_id AND c.attribute_id = (SELECT attribute_id FROM eav_attribute WHERE attribute_code = 'firstname' AND entity_type_id = b.entity_type_id)
INNER JOIN wishlist_item AS d ON a.wishlist_id = d.wishlist_id
INNER JOIN catalog_product_flat_1 AS e ON d.product_id = e.entity_id
LEFT JOIN sales_flat_order AS f ON f.customer_email = b.email
LEFT JOIN sales_flat_order_item AS g ON (f.entity_id = g.order_id AND g.sku LIKE CONCAT(e.sku,'%') AND g.product_type = 'simple')
GROUP BY b.email, c.value, a.updated_at, d.added_at, d.product_id, e.name
```

i am trying to start from something so i execute this query in phpmyadmin and i get no results.
Can somebody point me at least to the very beginning on how to get this collection in a template file or at least see the first results and start understanding how it works
I do understand that i should make even an admin module and filter the reports in a `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid`

**EDIT**: This query will work, problem was that catalog_product_flat_1 was empty in this Magento i work now, i have enabled the product flat tables in admin and now its ok. 
 Together with this module will do very easily the job https://github.com/kalenjordan/custom-reports for anyone else interest
Now i have another question, actually this is what i need to do:
How can i filter to a specify product using the exact Query?For example check product SKU (or product_id or name etc) and filter the results of the customers that have only this product in their wishlists.
Right now it will display all the products that every unique customer has in wishlist (huge query)

Comment: I am sorry but i realized that my query will bring results, i was testing in a database that has BubbleFullpagecache so i think i catalog_product_flat_1 brings nothing. In a normal magento shop it works. I will test more and i will update my question!

Comment: Updated Question with a solution i have found + added one more question for the SQL query.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer :)
final query includes target a specific product (no flat product data):

```
SELECT b.email, c.value AS firstname, a.updated_at, d.added_at, d.product_id, e.sku, SUM( g.qty_ordered ) AS purchased
FROM  `wishlist` AS a
INNER JOIN customer_entity AS b ON a.customer_id = b.entity_id
INNER JOIN customer_entity_varchar AS c ON a.customer_id = c.entity_id
AND c.attribute_id = ( 
SELECT attribute_id
FROM eav_attribute
WHERE attribute_code =  'firstname'
AND entity_type_id = b.entity_type_id ) 
INNER JOIN wishlist_item AS d ON a.wishlist_id = d.wishlist_id
INNER JOIN catalog_product_entity AS e ON d.product_id = e.entity_id
LEFT JOIN sales_flat_order AS f ON f.customer_email = b.email
LEFT JOIN sales_flat_order_item AS g ON ( f.entity_id = g.order_id
AND g.sku LIKE CONCAT( e.sku,  '%' ) 
AND g.product_type =  'simple' ) 
WHERE e.sku =  'api_75019'
GROUP BY b.email, c.value, a.updated_at, d.added_at, d.product_id, e.sku
```

and this for flat data enabled:

```
SELECT b.email, c.value AS firstname, a.updated_at, d.added_at, d.product_id, e.name, SUM( g.qty_ordered ) AS purchased
FROM  `wishlist` AS a
INNER JOIN customer_entity AS b ON a.customer_id = b.entity_id
INNER JOIN customer_entity_varchar AS c ON a.customer_id = c.entity_id
AND c.attribute_id = ( 
SELECT attribute_id
FROM eav_attribute
WHERE attribute_code =  'firstname'
AND entity_type_id = b.entity_type_id ) 
INNER JOIN wishlist_item AS d ON a.wishlist_id = d.wishlist_id
INNER JOIN catalog_product_flat_1 AS e ON d.product_id = e.entity_id
LEFT JOIN sales_flat_order AS f ON f.customer_email = b.email
LEFT JOIN sales_flat_order_item AS g ON ( f.entity_id = g.order_id
AND g.sku LIKE CONCAT( e.sku,  '%' ) 
AND g.product_type =  'simple' ) 
WHERE e.sku =  'api_75019'
GROUP BY b.email, c.value, a.updated_at, d.added_at, d.product_id, e.name
```